# How to convert 2001 based timestamp to datetime in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, datetime, timestamp

`ZPUBLICATIONDATETIME` is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

So when I do this:

```
SELECT strftime('%d - %m  - %Y ', datetime(ZPUBLICATIONDATETIME, 'unixepoch')) FROM ZTNNEWS;
```

I get `26 - 05  - 1984` instead of 2015. iOS (Core Data) writes datetime on `1 Jan 2001` based.  What is the best approach to get the right date conversion?

Shall I just add 31 years to it or is there an alternative to `unixepoch` to put in there?

Essentially what I am trying to do is to get the records from past two days:

```
select * 
from ZTNNEWS
where DATETIME(ZPUBLICATIONDATETIME) >  DATETIME('now', '-2 day')
```

But because `ZPUBLICATIONDATETIME` is of type `TIMESTAMP` rather than Datetime, it doesn't output anything.

Any advice please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just had the same problem. Adding the date value to the seconds of `1 Jan 2001` seems to do the job:

```
SELECT * FROM ztnnews WHERE DATETIME(zpublicationtime + 978307200) > DATETIME('now', '-2 day');
```

I used ruby to get the seconds of `1 Jan 2001`:

```
$ irb
2.2.3 :001 > require "time"
 => true 
2.2.3 :002 > Time.parse( "2001-01-01T00:00:00Z").to_i
 => 978307200
```