# 18 digit time stamp to local time within SQL query

Tags: sqlite

I am using DB Browser for SQlite.  My database also has date time stored in 18 digit time-stamp.   Please help to convert it to Local Time within this query:

```
SELECT * FROM message WHERE handle_id=52 ORDER BY date DESC;
```

I believe that this is a type of unix timestamp since the db is mac based. (Apple CoreD (nanosec) is the timestamp format, Thanks varro) Here are a couple of examples from the db:

```
561774860770410304 559334672583377600
```

I came across another similar question (18 digit timestamp to Local Time), but the asker didn't need the answer in any particular language or platform.

Thanks, Alice

Comment: That's not a unix timestamp, the value is too big. Current timestamp in seconds in around 1551214245 (run `date '+%s'` on your local unix machine to get it), even if ti would be in milliseconds, you're still 5 orders of magnitude off.

Comment: The macos APFS timestamps are 64-bit nanosecond resolution with UNIX epoch, so 559334672 is 09/22/1987 @ 6:44pm (UTC) and 561774860 is 10/21/1987 @ 12:34am (UTC)... do these make sense for your data?

Comment: No, the dates are within the past year or two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your case might be like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36822906/10498828. 
 The difference is that your date values are in nanoseconds, so you need first to divide with 1000000000:

```
select datetime(datecolumn/1000000000 + 978307200, 'unixepoch') from message
```

For these values:

```
561774860770410304 559334672583377600
```

the above code gives:

```
2018-10-21 00:34:20 2018-09-22 18:44:32
```

Comment: This works for me!  Thank you so much forpas!  And to everyone who also gave help and clues.

Answer (score 4):

Without knowing beforehand the timestamp format, it's impossible to give a definitive answer, but I submit this script (which depends on the sqlite3 command line tool only) to help:

```
#!/bin/sh

printf "Enter timestamp: "
read number

sqlite3 <<EOS
.mode column
.width 12, 20

select 'Number:',     $number;
select 'Unix epoch:', datetime($number, 'unixepoch');
select 'Variant:',    datetime($number, 'unixepoch', '-70 years');
select 'Julian day:', datetime($number);
select 'Mac HFS+:',   datetime($number, 'unixepoch', '-66 years');
select 'Apple CoreD:';
select '  (seconds)', datetime($number, 'unixepoch', '+31 years');
select '  (nanosec)', datetime($number/1000000000, 'unixepoch', '+31 years');
select 'NET:',        datetime($number/10000000, 'unixepoch', '-1969 years');
EOS
```

If you run this script and enter your number `561774860770410304`, you will see the following:

```
% Enter timestamp: 561774860770410304
Number:       561774860770410304
Unix epoch:   -
Variant:      -
Julian day:   -
Mac HFS+:     -
Apple CoreD:
  (seconds)   -
  (nanosec)   2018-10-21 00:34:20
NET:          1781-03-12 09:14:37
```

I will guess that probably "2018-10-21 00:34:20" is your timestamp, and that accordingly "Apple CoreD (nanosec)"" is your timestamp format (see https://www.epochconverter.com/coredata).

Comment: Yes, thank you, that matched my date.  It is Apple CoreD.

Comment: And it matched mine, it was NET.
Thank you !